# Deadlocks after extracting part of the trigger into a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, deadlock, database-deadlocks

Today we had very interesting case that mystifies me a lot. In a nutshell, we did some refactoring, cleaning up triggers from the repeated code, extracting it into the single and reusable stored procedure. We thought this refactoring will have no side-effects, but we were badly wrong. After the release, we encountered a lot of deadlocks and performance degradation with no evident reasons. After inspection of system tables to see what DB is taken by, we figured out that the refactoring above was involved and we ended up with rolling back the update.

We did not reproduce the issue in test environments to probe the cure yet, so some tricky conditions take place in order for issue to be visible.

The below are the details of what the change was about. We updated a lot of triggers, but all of them are very similar, I'll show you the one. It should be enough as I've found deadlock graph that shows that there is a deadlock where two processes were executing the single trigger (show below) and deadlocked.

Let me start with solution that worked before (that we rolled back to and that looks almost identical to deadlocking solution shown below as well).

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR__xyz__update_sync_publishers]
ON [dbo].[xyz]
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if(TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() = 1)
    BEGIN
        create table #AffectedIDs (advisor_id int primary key)

        insert into #AffectedIDs
            select distinct t.id
            from
                (select id 
                 from inserted
                 inner join xyz a ON a.id = id
                 where [text] <> ''
                 union 
                 select id 
                 from inserted
                 inner join xyz a ON a.id = id
                 where [text] <> '') t

        declare @date datetime = getutcdate()
        declare @RegisteredObjectTypeID int = 2
        declare @SyncPublisherSourceID int = 1

        update pub
        set pub.master_update_date = @date
        from #AffectedIDs affected
        inner join sync_publishers pub on 
            pub.sync_registered_object_type_id = @RegisteredObjectTypeID 
            and pub.sync_publisher_source_id = @SyncPublisherSourceID
            and pub.sync_object_id = affected.advisor_id

        insert into sync_publishers (sync_object_id, sync_registered_object_type_id, sync_publisher_source_id , master_update_date)
        select 
            affected.advisor_id,
            @RegisteredObjectTypeID,
            @SyncPublisherSourceID,
            @date
        from #AffectedIDs affected
        left join sync_publishers pub on 
            pub.sync_registered_object_type_id = @RegisteredObjectTypeID
            and pub.sync_publisher_source_id = @SyncPublisherSourceID
            and pub.sync_object_id = affected.advisor_id
        where 
            pub.sync_object_id is null

        drop table #AffectedIDs
    END
END
```

Here is the new trigger that deadlocks.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR__xyz__update_sync_publishers]
   ON [dbo].[xyz]
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @ids dtInt

    insert into @ids
    select distinct t.id
    from
    (
        select id from inserted
        INNER JOIN xyz a ON a.id = id
        WHERE [text] <> ''
        union 
        select id from inserted
        INNER JOIN xyz a ON a.id = id
        WHERE [text] <> ''
    ) t

    exec SyncTracker_PublishEvent 2, @ids

END
```

Here is the definition of extracted SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SyncTracker_PublishEvent]
    @objectTypeId int, 
    @ids dtInt readonly
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if(TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1) RETURN;

    declare @pubSourceId int = 1
    declare @date datetime = getutcdate()

    update pub
    set pub.master_update_date = @date
    from @ids affected
    inner join sync_publishers pub
    on pub.sync_registered_object_type_id = @objectTypeId 
        and pub.sync_publisher_source_id = @pubSourceId
        and pub.sync_object_id = affected.value

    insert into sync_publishers (sync_object_id, sync_registered_object_type_id, sync_publisher_source_id , master_update_date)
    select affected.value, @objectTypeId, @pubSourceId, @date
    from @ids affected
    left join sync_publishers pub
    on pub.sync_registered_object_type_id = @objectTypeId
        and pub.sync_publisher_source_id = @pubSourceId
        and pub.sync_object_id = affected.value
    where 
        pub.sync_object_id is null
END
GO
```

The definition of dtInt.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[dtInt] AS TABLE
(
    [value] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [value] ASC
    )
)
```

And finally the deadlock graph.

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="processe1892fe8c8" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="processe1892fe8c8" taskpriority="0" logused="3824" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057602924150784 (4776e78e2961)" waittime="5686" ownerId="2583257965" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2016-10-03T08:30:42.500" XDES="0xe192b24408" lockMode="U" schedulerid="6" kpid="41296" status="suspended" spid="141" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2016-10-03T08:30:42.503" lastbatchcompleted="2016-10-03T08:30:42.493" lastattention="2016-10-03T08:29:01.693" clientapp="..." hostname="..." hostpid="22572" loginname="kbuser" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2583257965" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="63c1b4d8-1c55-4429-b057-81fb6da8f780.dbo.SyncTracker_PublishEvent" line="21" stmtstart="1178" stmtend="1680" sqlhandle="0x030005007bf23c4b5012b40092a6000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
update pub
    set pub.master_update_date = @date
    from @ids affected
    inner join sync_publishers pub
    on pub.sync_registered_object_type_id = @objectTypeId 
        and pub.sync_publisher_source_id = @pubSourceId
        and pub.sync_object_id = affected.valu    </frame>
        <frame procname="63c1b4d8-1c55-4429-b057-81fb6da8f780.dbo.TR__xyz__update_sync_publishers" line="28" stmtstart="1300" stmtend="1372" sqlhandle="0x03000500f711233ddee4c60090a6000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
exec SyncTracker_PublishEvent 2, @id    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" line="1" stmtstart="1054" stmtend="3032" sqlhandle="0x02000000912653235c5ef3529289f19ae4445e62ee1ccbc00000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
    </process>
    <process id="processdfa401b848" taskpriority="0" logused="9384" waitresource="KEY: 5:72057602924150784 (1501093f83b4)" waittime="5814" ownerId="2582414029" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2016-10-03T08:30:09.933" XDES="0x104486ac408" lockMode="U" schedulerid="1" kpid="19548" status="suspended" spid="213" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2016-10-03T08:30:53.047" lastbatchcompleted="2016-10-03T08:30:53.047" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.047" clientapp="..." hostname="..." hostpid="6196" loginname="kbuser" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="2582414029" currentdb="5" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673316896" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="63c1b4d8-1c55-4429-b057-81fb6da8f780.dbo.SyncTracker_PublishEvent" line="21" stmtstart="1178" stmtend="1680" sqlhandle="0x030005007bf23c4b5012b40092a6000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
update pub
    set pub.master_update_date = @date
    from @ids affected
    inner join sync_publishers pub
    on pub.sync_registered_object_type_id = @objectTypeId 
        and pub.sync_publisher_source_id = @pubSourceId
        and pub.sync_object_id = affected.valu    </frame>
        <frame procname="63c1b4d8-1c55-4429-b057-81fb6da8f780.dbo.TR__xyz__update_sync_publishers" line="28" stmtstart="1300" stmtend="1372" sqlhandle="0x03000500f711233ddee4c60090a6000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
exec SyncTracker_PublishEvent 2, @id    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" line="1" stmtstart="1120" stmtend="3132" sqlhandle="0x020000007414d821ed68a2ab4462b4eca6b2fdb4ba28cc350000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
        <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown    </frame>
      </executionStack>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <keylock hobtid="72057602924150784" dbid="5" objectname="63c1b4d8-1c55-4429-b057-81fb6da8f780.dbo.sync_publishers" indexname="IX__sync_publishers__registered_object_type_id__sync_object_id" id="lock10887a96b00" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057602924150784">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="processdfa401b848" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="processe1892fe8c8" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
    <keylock hobtid="72057602924150784" dbid="5" objectname="63c1b4d8-1c55-4429-b057-81fb6da8f780.dbo.sync_publishers" indexname="IX__sync_publishers__registered_object_type_id__sync_object_id" id="lockdb7d7b8200" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057602924150784">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="processe1892fe8c8" mode="X" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="processdfa401b848" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </keylock>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

[image: deadlock graph]

The definition of sync_publishers available here: http://pastebin.com/LviwwCDi.

If you have any thoughts on feasible causes - please welcome to share - we will highly appreciate that!

**UPDATE 1. Actual execution plans for UPDATE/INSERT into sync_publishers**

Actual execution plans looks pretty much identical.

New exec plan (that occasionally deadlocks).
[image: new]

Old exec plan (that does not).
[image: old]

**UPDATE 2. Tried some advises**

I did try some advises today:

1. Got rid of "key lookups" in query plans due to missing `sync_publisher_source_id` within the non-clustered index by deletion column entirely -- it was not really mandatory in our implementation.
2. Rewrote `UPDATE + INSERT` as a single `MERGE` statement.

   ```
   MERGE sync_publishers2 t
   USING @ids s
   ON s.[value] = t.sync_object_id
       and t.sync_registered_object_type_id = @objectTypeId
   WHEN MATCHED
       THEN UPDATE
           SET master_update_date = @date
   WHEN NOT MATCHED
       THEN INSERT
                (sync_object_id, sync_registered_object_type_id, master_update_date)
           VALUES
                (s.[value], @objectTypeId, @date);
   ```

Started getting deadlocks on the `MERGE` statements. The new deadlock graph can be viewed here: http://pastebin.com/QNJk7tea.

**UPDATE 3. Trying MERGE hints**

I've tried to do `MERGE` with the `xlock` and `holdlock` hints -- with no luck though -- got a deadlock on MERGE again.

```
MERGE sync_publishers2 with(xlock, holdlock) t
```

Comment: Try check TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() in trigger body. In your proc version this code may run twice: `insert into @ids 
    select distinct t.id
    from()` which may badly affect the period of time the locks are held.

Comment: Check the actual execution plans of the "UPDATE pub" and "INSERT INTO sync_publishers" statements from the trigger vs. from the SP. Are you getting different execution plans due to the cardinality estimates?

Comment: @RazvanSocol, thanks for suggestion! I've update the post with actual execution plans for both cases -- looks pretty much identical...

Comment: Why does the Union sub query have two identical branches?  And why is there a Select Distinct of a Union [Distinct]?

Comment: @RBarryYoung, I think you are right on that, but do you suspect it to be related to the deadlocks? It works the same way in both approaches...

Comment: My concern is that it reflects a mistranslation for what you are showing us and something important may have been lost from the original.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, I see what you're saying and appreciate your attention to details! Even though I did alter this statement a bit, the semantic is the same. Here what really was in _both_ branches: "WHERE note_type_id = 4 AND note_text IS NOT NULL  AND note_text <> ''"

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov, without reading all the details, try to  use `WITH (HOLDLOCK)` hint for `MERGE`. See [“UPSERT” Race Condition With MERGE](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx).

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, thanks I did try it and, sadly, it's still deadlocking...

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov, I'd try to ask this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ Clean up your question and leave only the latest variant of the query with the latest schema, actual execution plan (use pastebin.com or something similar to post the full XML of the plan) and deadlock graph.

Comment: Have you tried checking your `trigger_nestlevel` before calling the stored procedure, rather than from within the stored procedure?  Something in the back of my head tells me that you may be getting something odd when testing this outwith a trigger....

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet, no, I have not. I'll try to experiment with this matter more today.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the version that does not seem to deadlock after 1+ hour of 3 workload session in parallel. I can not really spot the exact reason of deadlocks in a first place, but what I can do is to stress out difference with deadlocking try that was also embracing the MERGE statement: the version bellow (that seems to work OK) uses CTE to allow `MERGE`'s `ON` expression to be rewritten in a way to only mention PK column (`sync_publisher_id`).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SyncTracker_PublishEvent2]
    @objectTypeId int, 
    @ids dtInt readonly
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- stop recoursive propogations
    if(TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1) RETURN;

    declare @date datetime = getutcdate()

    ;WITH sync_publishers2CTE AS
    (
        SELECT [sync_publisher_id],
                [sync_object_id],
                [sync_registered_object_type_id],
                [master_update_date]
            FROM [dbo].[sync_publishers2] 
            WHERE sync_registered_object_type_id = @objectTypeId
    )
    MERGE sync_publishers2CTE WITH (XLOCK) trg
    USING 
    (
            SELECT sp.sync_publisher_id,
                    s.Value AS sync_object_id,
                    @objectTypeId AS sync_registered_object_type_id,
                    @date AS master_update_date
                FROM @ids s 
                LEFT JOIN sync_publishers2 sp ON sp.sync_object_id = s.Value
                                                AND sp.sync_registered_object_type_id = @objectTypeId 
    ) src
    ON (trg.sync_publisher_id = src.sync_publisher_id)
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN UPDATE
            SET trg.master_update_date = src.master_update_date
    WHEN NOT MATCHED
        THEN INSERT
                 (sync_object_id, sync_registered_object_type_id, master_update_date)
            VALUES
                 (sync_object_id, sync_registered_object_type_id, master_update_date);
END
```

The sample execution plan:

[image: exec plan]